# How can i make both the chapter name and the book-title name appear when citing a book using the Vancouver style in latex?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, natbib

```
@BOOK{Khalil2002,
    title = {Gain-Scheduling},
    publisher = {Prentice Hall, Inc.},
    year = {2002},
    author = {Khalil, H. K},
    booktitle = {Nonlinear Systems},
}
```

%The title of the book is Nonlinear Systems and the chapter title is Gain-Scheduling. It look like this in sharelatex:

[image]

Comment: You should likely use the `@inbook` entry type.

Comment: You should either use `@inbook` or `@incollection` depending on whether the book is an edited book with chapters by different authors or not. See [Bad bibtex entries using InBook](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/323357) for some more detailed explanation.

Comment: @DavidPurton Do you want to type up a quick answer here, or do we close this as a duplicate of the question linked by Alan?

Answer (score 1):

To cite a chapter within a book, you should use the `inbook` entry type.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inbook{khalil2002,
  author = {Khalil, Hassan K.},
  title = {Gain-Scheduling},
  booktitle = {Nonlinear Systems},
  publisher = {Prentice Hall, Inc.\isdot},
  date = {2002}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]